# How to choose minimum elements from an array whose sum is greater or equals p?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am dealing with a problem where I need to greedily choose some elements whose sum greater or equals to `p`. Here , another condition is that the difference between the total sum of chosen array elements and given p is as minimum as possible.

Say the array is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and given p is `10`.Here the optimal answer might be to choose `[1,4,5]`,sum=10 and p=10 difference is 0.

> **My approach** is always choose the max elements from the array then if
> tot sum exceeds then choose the min elements and reduce the difference

But that did not work out. If the array is `[2,4,5,6,7,8]` and p is `16` the optimal answer would be to choose `[2,6,8]` which can not be done with my approach. I am assuming maybe `dp` would be helpful here but as I am a newbie so could not get the idea how to implement. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Which condition has higher priority? Let's say 3 elements produce p+2 and 2 elements produce p+3 which solution is preferable?

Comment: no.not about 3 elements.I just show you an example.the array length can be 10^5.so only two or 3 elements is not the case here.And both the conditions must be fulfilled. diffrence minimum and minimum elements

Comment: Duh 3 elements is for example. "And both the conditions must be fulfilled." I am asking again, lets say you have 2 solutions, a) 1000 elements with sum=P+2 b) 1001 elements with sum=P+1, which solution is preferable?

Comment: oh sorry ,I misread. In such case minimum element must be fullfilled. So (a) is the key

Comment: Do you need to find exact solution?  I am afraid this is NP-complete. Anyway you probably want to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Can there be duplicates in the input array?  Do you just need the minimum **count** of elements, or the entire set of elements?

Comment: If the input array is `[2,4,8,16,29,32]` and `p=30`, which is the solution? The 4 element solution: `[2,4,8,16]` or the 2 element solution: `[2,29]` ?

Comment: minimum number is the solution.so [2,29].and there can be duplicates sir

Comment: If that's then case, why would `[6,7,8]` be an incorrect solution for your example of `[2,4,5,6,7,8] with p=16` ?  It meets the requirement of smallest element count (3) and who's sum is "greater than or equal to p" ?

Comment: @selbie if count of elements is the same then sum should be as close as possible. See my questions

Comment: Let's say you had `[2,3,5,6]` and `p=8`.  You have both `[2,6]` and `[3,5]` as candidate solutions?  Which one wins?

Comment: @selbie If you take [6,7,8] total sum would be 21.Here the diff from p is 21-16=5;But in [2,8,6] here dif=16-16=0;So second one is the answer as mentioned."Let's say you had [2,3,5,6] and p=8. You have both [2,6] and [3,5] as candidate solutions? Which one wins?"- here both conditions are fullfilled in both solutions then anyone can be the winner

Comment: Help me make sure I have the right understanding. I'm going to call a **candidate solution**, any set of integers in the original input set who's sum is greater than or equal to `p`.  When comparing two candidate solutions, the smaller sized set wins.  But when comparing two candidate solutions that are of the same size, the one with the summation closest to `p` wins.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.that approach would work